# JPA: Adding new entry to a many-to-many taking long time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

im having a problem when adding a new entry in a many-to-many relationship because the list is huge. Ex:

```
Item item = new Item(1);
Category cat = dao.find(1, Category.class);
List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(cat);
item.setCategoryList(list);
cat.getItemList().add(item);
```

The problem is that the Category Itens list is huge, with a lot of itens, so performing the cat.getItemList() takes a very long time. Everywhere i look for the correct way to add a many-to-many entry says that a need to do that. Can someone help?

Edit:
A little context: I organize my itens with tags, so 1 item can have multiple tags and 1 tag can have multiple itens, the time has pass and now i have tags with a lot of itens ( > 5.000), and now when i save a new item with one of thoses tags it takes a long time, i have debuged my code and found that most of the delay is in the cat.getItensList() line, with makes sense since it has a extensive list o itens. I have searched a lot for how to do this, and everyone says that the correct way to save a entry in a many-to-many case is to add to the list on both sides of the relationship, but if one side is huge, it will takes a lot of time since calling the getItensList() loads them in the context. Im looking for a way to save my item refering the tag witout loading all of the itens of that tag.

Edit 2:
My classes:
Item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transacao")
@XmlRootElement
 public class Transacao implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "transacaoList")
    private List<Tagtransacao> tagtransacaoList;
    ...(other stuff)
}
```

Tag:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tagtransacao")
@XmlRootElement
public class Tagtransacao implements Serializable {
  @JoinTable(name = "transacao_has_tagtransacao", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "tagtransacao_idTagTransacao", referencedColumnName = "idTagTransacao")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "transacao_idTransacao", referencedColumnName = "idTransacao")})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Transacao> transacaoList;
...(other stuff)
}
```

Edit 3:
**WHAT I DID TO SOLVE:**
As answered by Ariel Kohan, i tried to do a NativeQuery to insert the relationship:

```
  Query query = queryDAO.criarNativeQuery("INSERT INTO " + config.getNomeBanco() + ".`transacao_has_tagtransacao` "
            + "(`transacao_idTransacao`, `tagtransacao_idTagTransacao`) VALUES (:idTransacao, :idTag);");
    query.setParameter("idTransacao", transacao.getIdTransacao());
    query.setParameter("idTag", tag.getIdTagTransacao());
```

I was able to reduce the time of que query from 10s to 300milis what it is impressive. In the end its better for my project that it is already runnig to do that instead of creating a new class that represents the many-to-many reletionship. Thanks to everyone who tried to help \o/

Comment: 5,000 is not particularly large and I think it should be loaded only once, but if you want to insert a relation directly then you can make a join entity specifically (requires building a composite key, plenty of examples), and insert the new relation on that entity. That should be able to do so without having to read the anything first.

Comment: But if i use a composite key class for the many to many relationship, wouldt i have to get the list of this class on both sides and add this class, just like i have to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would prevent your code from load the item list in memory.

To do that, I can think about two options:

### Using a `@Modyfing` query to insert the items directly in the DB.

[Recommended for cases where you want to avoid changing your model]

You can try to create the query using normal JPQL but, depending on your model, you may need to use a native query. Using native query would be something like this:

```
@Query(value = "insert into ...", nativeQuery = true)
void addItemToCategory(@Param("param1") Long param1, ...);
```

After creating this query, you will need to update your code removing the parts where you load the objects in memory and adding the parts to call the insert statements.

> **[Update]**
>   As you mentioned in a comment, doing this improved your performance from 10s to 300milis.

---

### Modify your Entities in order to replace `@ManyToMany` with `@OneToMany`s relationship

The idea in this solution is to replace a ManyToMany relationship between entities `A` and `B` with an intermediate entity `RelationAB`. I think you can do this in two ways:

1. Save only the Ids from A and B in RelationAB as a composite key (of course you can add other fields like a Date or whatever you want).
2. Add an auto-generated Id to RelationAB and add A and B as other fields in the RelationAB entity.

I did an example using the first option (you will see that the classes are not public, this is just because I decided to do it in a single file for the sake of simplicity. Of course, you can do it in multiple files and with public classes if you want):

`Entities A and B`:

```
@Entity
class EntityA  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public EntityA() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

@Entity
class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    public EntityB() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

`RelationABEntity` and `RelationABId`:

```
@Embeddable
class RelationABId implements Serializable {
    private Long entityAId;
    private Long entityBId;

    public RelationABId() {
    }

    public RelationABId(Long entityAId, Long entityBId) {
        this.entityAId = entityAId;
        this.entityBId = entityBId;
    }

    public Long getEntityAId() {
        return entityAId;
    }

    public void setEntityAId(Long entityAId) {
        this.entityAId = entityAId;
    }

    public Long getEntityBId() {
        return entityBId;
    }

    public void setEntityBId(Long entityBId) {
        this.entityBId = entityBId;
    }
}

@Entity
class RelationABEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RelationABId id;

    public RelationABEntity() {
    }

    public RelationABEntity(Long entityAId, Long entityBId) {
        this.id = new RelationABId(entityAId, entityBId);
    }

    public RelationABId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(RelationABId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

My Repositories:

```
@Repository
interface RelationABEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<RelationABEntity, RelationABId> {

}

@Repository
interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Long> {


}

@Repository
interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityB, Long> {

}
```

A test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class DemoApplicationTest {

    @Autowired RelationABEntityRepository relationABEntityRepository;
    @Autowired ARepository aRepository;
    @Autowired BRepository bRepository;


    @Test
    public void test(){
        EntityA a = new EntityA();
        a = aRepository.save(a);
        EntityB b = new EntityB();
        b = bRepository.save(b);

        //Entities A and B in the DB at this point

        RelationABId relationABID = new RelationABId(a.getId(), b.getId());

        final boolean relationshipExist = relationABEntityRepository.existsById(relationABID);
        assertFalse(relationshipExist);

        if(! relationshipExist){
            RelationABEntity relation = new RelationABEntity(a.getId(), b.getId());
            relationABEntityRepository.save(relation);
        }

        final boolean relationshipExitNow = relationABEntityRepository.existsById(relationABID);
        assertTrue(relationshipExitNow);
        /**
         * As you can see, modifying your model you can create relationships without loading big list and without complex queries. 
         */
    }    
}
```

The code above explains another way to handle this kind of things. Of course, you can make modifications according to what you exactly need.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I edited the question with more context. Writing the query probably would solve my problem, but is a complex object and i would rather use the JPA's EntityManager and Pojos. In last case i will write the query, thanks for the answer

Comment: Ok I think that I understand now. Is that relationship bidirectional? Please try to only add the category to the item and don't add the item to the `cat.getItemList()` and see what happened when you save that. If that doesn't work, please add some of your model (specially the lines where you define the @ManyToMany relationship)

Comment: They are bidirectional, so add on only 1 side dont work. I edited again with the classes). I wrote the query and reduce the time from 10s to 300milis, but steel it seems wrong that something so simple and used would generate that mucht problem (sorry for my english)

Comment: Glad to hear that, incredible optimization. However, I understand and you are right, we can make something cleaner. I'm going to edit the answer giving you the other option that is similar to what @K.Nicholas suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically copied from a similar answer I gave earlier but similar question as well. The code below ran when I first write it but I changed the names to match this question so there might be some typos. The spring-data-jpa is a layer on top of JPA. Each entity has its own repository and you have to deal with that. For dealing with the many-to-many relations specifically in spring-data-jpa you can make a separate repository for the link table if you think it's a good idea.

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ItemCategory> categories;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ItemCategory> items;

@Entity
public class ItemCategory {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemcategoryId id = new ItemcategoryId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("itemId")
    private Item Item;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("categoryId")
    private Category category;

    public ItemCategory() {}
    public ItemCategory(Item Item, Category category) {
        this.item = item;
        this.category = category;
    }

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class ItemCategoryId implements Serializable {
    private Long itemId;
    private Long categoryId;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        ItemCategoryId that = (ItemCategoryId) o;
        return Objects.equals(itemId, that.itemId) && Objects.equals(categoryId, that.categoryId);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(itemId, categoryId);
    }
```

And to use it. Step 3 shows the way you are currently doing it and creates a read of the existing joins before doing the update. Step 4 just inserts a relation directly in the join table and does not cause a pre-read of the existing joins.

```
@Transactional
private void update() {
    System.out.println("Step 1");
    Category category1 = new Category();
    Item item1 = new Item();
    ItemCategory i1c1 = new ItemCategory(Item1, Category1);
    categoryRepo.save(Category1);
    ItemRepo.save(Item1);
    ItemCategoryRepo.save(p1t1);

    System.out.println("Step 2");
    Category category2 = new Category();
    Item item2 = new Item();
    ItemCategory p2t2 = new ItemCategory(item2, category2);
    ItemRepo.save(item2);
    categoryRepo.save(category2);
    ItemCategoryRepo.save(p2t2);

    System.out.println("Step 3");
    category2 = CategoryRepo.getOneWithitems(2L);
    category2.getitems().add(new ItemCategory(item1, category2));
    categoryRepo.save(Category2);

    System.out.println("Step 4 -- better");
    ItemCategory i2c1 = new ItemCategory(item2, category1);
    itemCategoryRepo.save(i2c1);
}
```

I don't explicitly set the `ItemCategoryId` id's. These are handled by the persistence layer (hibernate in this case).

Note also that you can update `ItemCategory` entries either explicity with its own repo or by adding and removing them from the list since `CascadeType.ALL` is set, as shown. The problem with using the `CascadeType.ALL` for spring-data-jpa is that even though you prefetch the join table entities spring-data-jpa will do it again anyway. Trying to update the relationship through the `CascadeType.ALL` for new entities is problematic.

Without the `CascadeType` neither the `items` or `categories` lists (which should be Sets) are the owners of the relationship so adding to them wouldn't accomplish anything in terms of persistence and would be for query results only.

When reading the `ItemCategory` relationships you need to specifically fetch them since you don't have `FetchType.EAGER`. The problem with `FetchType.EAGER` is the overhead if you don't want the joins and also if you put it on both `Category` and `Item` then you will create a recursive fetch that gets all `categories` and `items` for any query.

```
@Query("select c from Category c left outer join fetch c.items is left outer join fetch is.Item where t.id = :id")
Category getOneWithItems(@Param("id") Long id);
```